# ZKemkeeper taking long time when reding ReadGeneralLogData

Tags: time-and-attendance

We are using C# ZKempkeeper (CZKEMClass) dlls to downloading attendance data from biometric/finger scanning machines.

Some time the code is working fine, but mostly its taking long time and even not giving time out error. This is the line where compiler stuck and never come back

```
status = zkemkeeper.ReadAllGLogData(iMachineNumber);
```

Comment: what is the count in the machine?

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced the same problem before. I had to run it as administrator because the main project is using an external DLL.

Answer (score -1):

try

> Actually, from the screen only ZKEMSDK.DLL and "Visual C++ 2003
>   runtime" is missing but required. The other DLLs above is "normal" to
>   be missing and will not harm your application's functionality.
>
> Unfortunately since seems Microsoft have removed downloads for C++
>   runtime before VC2005, you should use the DLL that comes with the
>   package.
>
> Also, make sure your program compile as "x86" instead of "Any CPU" or
>   it won't find the DLL on 64-bit systems. (The fact that it depends on
>   VC++ 2003 runtime implies this must be 32-bit DLL)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11fbbd80-cf40-4ecd-8f73-26785cb32383/unable-to-use-zkemkeeperdll-from-64-bit-computer?forum=netfxbcl